# Suppress executed code line display in ipython console while debugging

Tags: debugging, console, ipython, spyder

How do I suppress the currently being executed python line of code from being displayed in ipython console while debugging? I am using spyder and I do not want the currently executed code line to be displayed in the ipython console while debugging as I already have it in the Spyder editor.

Is there a way to do that? Please see screenshot. Thanks for help!

[Code snippet in ipython console that i want to hide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q7441.png)

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder developer here*) Executing lines or cells of code while debugging **doesn't** work in Spyder 3, but it'll work as expected in Spyder 4 (to be released in six to eight months).